# Can I pass a parameter from URL to Livewire Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am new to Laravel Livewire. I want to be able to use the parameter passed from the URL in the Laravel livewire blade file. I have been able to access the parameter in the controller from the route, performed the logic and pass it to the component blade view file, but I am a bit confused how to **pass** or access the object passed to the component view file in the livewire view file where the display logic is located.

I have the major files and codes involved in this scenario:

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/productcategory/{category}', [App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::class, 'productCategory'])->name('productcategory');
```

App/HTTP/controller/CategoryController.php

```
public function productCategory($category)
    {
        $cat = str_replace("+"," ",$category);
        $categories = Categories::all();
        $products= Product::where('category', $cat)->paginate(10);
        return view('components.productcategories', compact('categories','products'));
    }
```

resources/view/component/productcategories.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.newapp')

@section('title','Product Category')
@section('content')
<div>
    @include('inc.header')

    @livewire('category')
   
    @include('inc.footer')
</div>
@endsection
```

App/HTTP/livewire/Productcategory.php

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.category');
    }
```

resources/view/livewire/category.blade.php

```
@if (!empty($products))
  @foreach ($products as $item)
     <p>{{ $item->name}}</p>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Please I need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it in the `@livewire()` directive like just make sure that the `$product` is declared to your livewire component class:

**Blade Component**

```
@livewire('category', [
    'products' => $products,
])
```

**Livewire Class**

```
class Productcategory
{
    public $products

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.category');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using route model binding, it'll be [automatically provided to the `mount` function](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#route-model-binding):

```
public $category;

public function mount(Category $category)
{
    $this->category = $category;
}
```

In PHP 7.4+, you can skip the `mount()` so it's even simpler; just declare the parameter and match the class and variable name from your routes file.

```
class YourLivewireComponent extends Component
{
    public Category $category;
}
```

If you just wanted to get a random GET parameter, inject the Request class:

```
public $foo;

public function mount(Request $request)
{
    $this->foo = $request->get('foo');
}
```

(You can inject any dependency this way, not just Request.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been able to do as you have shown, but then another problem came up. I now get an error saying 
`Object of class App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController could not be converted to string`
Here is the code I ran. 

`public function mount(CategoryController $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.productcategory',[
            'products'=> Product::where('category', $this->category)->paginate(12),
            'categories'=> Categories::all(),
        ]);;
    }`

Comment: @Chizo You're probably trying to display `$categories` in your Blade file.

Comment: Not exactly @ceejayoz. I am trying to display products in the DB that matches $categories.